# minimal value of $x^2+2y^2+5z^2$ with constraint.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

$x,y,z>0$, and $xy+yz+zx=1$.
I need to find the minimum value of 
$x^2+2y^2+5z^2$ 
In general what can we say about the minimal value of $\frac{ax^2+by^2+cz^2}{xy+xz+yz}$, over all positive numbers with $a,b,c>0 $

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html

Comment: Is this a problem from Peruvian MO?

Comment: yes it is from MO, but i don't know what country is .

Answer (score 3):

Using AM-GM, we have:
$$4x^2+9y^2 \ge 12xy$$
$$3y^2+12z^2 \ge 12yz$$
$$18z^2+2x^2\ge 12zx$$
Combining and using the constraint, 
$$6x^2+12y^2+30z^2 \ge 12(xy+yz+zx) \implies x^2+2y^2+5z^2 \ge 2$$
Equality is when $x:y:z = 3:2:1$ and satisfying the constraint, i.e. when $x = \frac3{\sqrt{11}}, y = \frac2{\sqrt{11}}, z = \frac1{\sqrt{11}}$.

In general for $ax^2+by^2+cz^2$, you can construct similar inequalities using unknown coefficients to start with, which you solve to keep the equality condition and match LHS / RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the lagrange problem :
$x^2+2y^2+5z^2-\lambda(xy+yz+zx-1)$

Then deriving with respect to x gives : $2x=\lambda(y+z)$

y : $4y=\lambda(x+z)$

z : $10z=\lambda(x+y)$

So we have $(10+\lambda)z=(4+\lambda)y=(2+\lambda)x$.

Comment: How did you arrive at $3x=5y=11z$?

Comment: I'm sorry this is a mistake